# What is the correct syntax for this if statement in nginx

Tags: nginx

Due to a migration I need to redirect traffic from /index.php?page=1 to /page/1. I only want the rule to fire if a specific parameter has been set (page in this example). From what I understand the following should work:

```
location = /index.php {
    if($arg_page) {
        return 301 $scheme://test.mydomain.com/page/$arg_page;
    }
}
```

However this fails, the entire site fails to load. When I take out the if statement it works, but then all traffic to URL's that start with /index.php is redirected. It should *only* redirect if the query parameter "page" is present. What am I missing here?

Comment: Show full config and error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try -

```
if ($arg_page) {
    rewrite ^/index.php $scheme://test.mydomain.com/page/$arg_page? permanent;
}
```